# Compilation order in Grails when using together with Scala plugin

Tags: scala, grails, groovy

Doing some POC and ran into problem - in my grails project scala code I use some types from grails/groovy and since 'grails compile' runs scala compiler first - those types are not accessible for me. How I can change the order to compile grails/groovy source first and then go with scala bits?

Comment: not sure, but does putting your scala code under `src/java` help?

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately does not help neither src/java neither src/scala

Comment: hmm I remember a JIRA about compilation issues when using Domain Classes inside Java classes but I didn't find it. This issue may have a answer to your problem.

Comment: Could not find anything within grails jira, so a ticket for this http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSCALA-5